# Subversion update and maven auto build updated modules

Tags: svn, maven

Our team has a project consisting of 40 subprojects. We develop in a distribute fashion, which means every morning, we have to update the changes from other teams and rebuild the whole project. The problem is the build now take an hour, which is unbearable. I wonder is there any tool that can "understand" the updates and only build the updated subprojects in a correct manner. Sometimes, when the updates are not big, i did this manually. But when the updates are so huge, it's hard to keep track of.

Any recommendations or suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a multi-module build ? Or are you talking about a CI environment like Jenkins / Hudson ?

Answer (score 1):

Use Continues Integration server (I recommend Jenkins) along with internal Maven repository (like Nexus). Most CIs are smart enough to figure out what project's modules has changed and rebuild them only. After successful build, CI should deploy your current SNAPSHOTs to Maven repository so other developers immediately see the changed stuff they depend on. Of course, they still need to update code they're working on, but usually that's only few modules while all other dependencies are downloaded from Nexus as they changed. And by the way, you're getting all other Continues Integration advantages like continues automatic testing etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use SNAPSHOTs (make your whole project versioned 1.0-SNAPSHOT), and only checkout or build the modules you are working in. You can update to the latest copy of the SNAPSHOT with mvn -U, to get the latest binaries for the other dependencies which other developers made changes to...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am not sure about the consequences of the mvn -U command. Is is equivalent to my old method, i.e., update all the code and rebuild ?